# Problem in count a query in database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the row count in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162571/how-do-i-get-the-row-count-in-jdbc)

Hi,

How can I count a query in a row in `MySQL` database using sql count statement with `JAVA`?

tq

Comment: The question is not very clear - can you expand a bit?

Comment: @user661820: Have you try google the answer? Here's one of the first result: http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0003

Comment: you mean, "How to execute SQL count query from Java?"

Answer (score 1):

How about

`select count(*) from`*`table_name`*

Usage would be something like:

```
     int count;
     String table = ...
     Statement st = ...
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select count(*) from " + table);
     while (rs.next()){
      count = rs.getInt(1);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a query to get the count :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
```