# Get row count of successful bulk insert using jdbc from sql server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have Java code to bulk-insert tab file to SQL Server.
I want to get the count of how many records were inserted. I tried using @@rowcount but I'm getting an error that "Statement did not return a result set". 
If I run the bulk insert statement in management studio, I can get the count.

```
Statement stmt = sqlConnection.createStatement();         
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ("BULK INSERT schema1.table1 FROM 'd:\temp1\file1.tab' SELECT @@rowcount");
```

Is there any way to get the inserted count?

Comment: Perhaps something like the following? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10139221/6492765

Comment: what is happening when you use execute(query) statement instead of executequery(query)

Comment: This could help! http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/RetrievearowcountfromaResultSet.htm

Comment: @ErayBalkanli execute returns false so cant get count.
Those examples are of select statements which works fine. Mine is "Bulk Insert" which gives the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SQL Server but it seems like you'll want to issue an executeUpdate instead of an executeQuery

```
Statement stmt = sqlConnection.createStatement();         
int insertedRowCount = stmt.executeUpdate("BULK INSERT schema1.table1 FROM 'd:\temp1\file1.tab'");
```

Comment: This gives me row count. But in my bulk insert statement, I have batch size=1000 so this always return 1000 but my file has lets say 5000 entries.